# Use the same search box to search different types of data

Tags: search, input-fields, html

I'm trying to figure out an elegant solution to this problem, but haven't had any great ideas.  ([This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66879/single-search-box-for-different-types-of-searched-criteria) is similar but doesn't really answer my issue)

We allow our users to search different types of data from the same input box, but only searching one set of data at a time. (e.g. searching for cars or people but not both at the same time).

Currently we have a search box with a dropdown arrow that looks something like this: [image]

Clicking the arrow drops down a list letting them select a different category to search.

Is there a better/nicer way to implement this sort of functionality?

Edit to clarify: I really do like the idea of a single search box without forcing the user to choose a category. However, technical limitations mean that this design is not feasible at this time, so Ades answer was the best solution for me.

Comment: The most obvious better/nicer solution is to not force the user to select the type of search. Is there a technical reason for the restriction?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey A few, including performance and accuracy of results (we're not really Google `:)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just follow the established search form similar to Amazon one (see below). If the user doesn't select a particular category, then it would search all categories for that particular keyword.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think search should be a 1-step thing and the categorization should be done by the software/app. *If possible, allow the user to search in multiple categories.* [Technically speaking, you can use [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) for this purpose]

One good example of such technique is the older version of Spotlight on Mac. 
[image: spotlight on mac]

The user types his search query and the system categorizes it based on metadata. We followed this example while developing search for our website.

Hope this helps!

[image: search inspired by spotlight]

Comment: The OP clearly states, and confirms the reasons why in comments, that they can not use a single search solution.  How can the OP adjust this solution for their restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

On Google map (for exemple) you have also one research input field to search many different things (restaurant, street, address, hostel...)
So you could use the same behavior :

[image]

[image]

A smart research, but I would add exemples in the input field, like this : 
[image]

You can compile this solution, keeping the category dropdown menu. Here the user has the choice.